# Changing the size and start position of a webview inside a TableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I'm making an app that uses a webview inside a TableviewCell and I was wondering if there is a way to make the webview a lot smaller so it doesn't fill up the whole cell. I've tried all the obvious things such as changing the CGRectMake dimensions and changed the size in the storyboard but it keeps taking up the whole cell. I was also wondering if there was a way to load the webpage at a certain place on the website.

This is the code I have so far...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSDictionary *myModel = feeds[indexPath.row];


    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.customName.text = [myModel objectForKey: @"author"];
    cell.customDate.text = [myModel objectForKey: @"pubDate"];


    UIWebView* CellWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(5, 5, cell.bounds.size.width - 5, cell.bounds.size.height - 5)];
    [CellWebview setOpaque:NO];
    [CellWebview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[CellWebview scrollView] setScrollEnabled:YES];

    self.url = [myModel objectForKey:@"link"];
    [CellWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: self.url]]];
    [cell addSubview:CellWebview];
     CellWebview.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)CellWebview{
    CGSize contentSize = CellWebview.scrollView.contentSize;
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

    float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;

    CellWebview.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
    CellWebview.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
    CellWebview.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;

    CellWebview.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to be adding the web view to the cell’s `contentView`, not to the cell directly.

Comment: The webview still takes up the whole cell when it's in content view as well

Comment: `CGRectMake(5, 5, cell.bounds.size.width - 5, cell.bounds.size.height - 5)` Is going to make it nearly the size of the cell. What if you pass a constant, like 40, for width and height?